# Laptop not suspending on lid close

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lid

I have a Dell Inspiron 5570 with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and an external monitor and I have followed many articles, used gnome tweaks and more but my laptop will not suspend on the closing of the lid but it moves the things on the other screen and doesn't suspend.

I've tried editing lid close and lid close on dock but none of these things have worked.

If anyone has any ideas or anything that can help, please let me know, thanks!